# Symfony2 firewall doesn't match check_path

Tags: php, symfony

I've tried to resolve that looking for all the answers but I can't resolve it. I receive the error **"Unable to find the controller for path /login_check"** when I try to log in. In theory the check_path is behind the firewall...

Here is my `security.yml`

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern:  ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: frontend_login
                check_path: frontend_login_check
                remember_me: true
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: perfil
            logout:
                path: frontend_logout
                target: frontend_login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/perfil/*, roles: ROLE_USER }

    providers:
        usuarios:
            entity: { class: TicketRunner\TicketRunnerBundle\Entity\User, property: email }

    encoders:
        TicketRunner\TicketRunnerBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
```

And here is my `routing.yml`

```
frontend_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: TicketRunnerTicketRunnerBundle:User:login }

frontend_login_check:
    pattern: /login_check
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the default check_path: /login_check ?

Comment: Because there still has to be a route that matches that pattern/path.

Comment: Is your routing.yml file being loaded and the routes aren't being overwritten, can you see the routes when you run `app/console router:debug`? Another obvious one is the usual `app/console cache:clear` question.

Comment: I also tried `check_path: /login_check`, route appears in `app/console router:debug`

Comment: Everything seems to be in order in your configuration. There must be something simple you're missing (or something you haven't shown us). In such scenaro, I'd try to configure it in separation of your project, on a fresh installation of the Symfony Standard Edition.

Comment: I found the solution! Incredible but I forgot to add method="post" to the form... so stupid. Thanks to all!